# jQuery UI - icon alignment

Tags: css, jquery-ui

In the following example, I'm trying to get the text, input box and icon to align without over lapping.

http://jsfiddle.net/zGZM7/2/

Is there some css I'm missing?

Thanks

Edit, sadly I need a solution which will work with FF and IE6 :(

Comment: Do you mean all elements on the same line, without wrapping to the next line?

Comment: @andyb yes, sorry that's exactly what I'm looking for. Niklas has provided a solution which works. Thanks

Comment: not a problem, I just wanted to be clear :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a lot of irrelevant CSS in your fiddle and the only relevant bit isn't getting called as it in your example requires to be under a `ul` with id `#icons`. Removing the `ul#icons` with the following:

```
.ui-icon {float: left; margin: 0 4px;}
```

Should make it work as you described.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/kTFw7/

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for, sorry about the extra css. Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: Sorry to be a pest. I've tested in FF and this is great, but in IE6, it's still on a new line. Is there a way round this? thanks.

Comment: @Raoul You could with conditionals display it to IE6 users with this kind of CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/kTFw7/25/ (note the inline td width as well)

Answer (score 0):

Split them in different tds

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
        <td><input type=text id=Foo class=textInput></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

or

add style float:left to the input

```
<td>
  <input type=text id=Foo class=textInput style="float:left">
  <a href="#" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></a>
</td>
```

or like Niklas's idea

```
 .ui-icon {float: right; margin: 0 2px;}
```